# Debugging JavaScript in VS Code Console

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

How can I quickly test JavaScript in the VSCode Console as shown in the picture below? Do I have to install an extension to do this? I'm using VSCode in both Ubuntu and Windows 10 but I'm not seeing *Console*. All I see is *Debug Console*, *Problems*, *Output* and *Terminal*. I'm currently using the Quokka extension but I would really like to test JS in the way pictured below without having to open a browser to do that.

[image: Testing JS in VSCode Console]

EDIT 2
Chrome JavaScript Console is used in conjunction with an index.html file and VSCode. I really wish the JS Console was built into VSCode.
[image]

Comment: You could always try running `node` from the Terminal

Comment: Also, this is what unit tests are for. You should write some. Jest is pretty easy to set up.

Comment: @Phil yes I currently use node to run my programs but I was wondering how i can also test them in VSCode as shown in the picture, the same way i would test it using Chrome dev tools in the browser.

Comment: That picture looks exactly the same as the chrome devtools. I reckon they just got a devtools window and put it on the side of the screen.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for recommending Jest. I'm researching it now.

Comment: @Aplet123 I think you are right, I thought this was a feature of VSCode that i did not know about.

Comment: You might find it difficult to test your JS files if you're writing them for the browser (eg functions declared in the `window` scope). I'm not actually sure what best practices are for that these days but hopefully somebody here does

Comment: @Phil I'm currently focused on NodeJs apps

Comment: @Sparky ah ok, I'm just going off the code in your screenshot

Comment: Quokka requires a license to run. I had it myself for a long time, but they started yelling at me after my 1 year license expired and i got annoyed with it. VS Code debugger is the way to go for me now.

Comment: I'm using Quokka.js Community edition (free). It's great but it keeps reminding me that i'm using the community edition and asks me to try the Pro edition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open `launch.json`

Then **paste** this entire chunk if empty, or add the single object to an existing list.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Node: Current File",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when you **click** on the **Debug** menu (the bug **>** button) on the side panel (or press <kbd>F5</kbd>), You'l have a `Node: Current File` as a run time dropdown option that will execute your JS via Node, and display the results in the attached VSC terminal.

[image: Debug Menu RUN Options]
[image: See Terminal output on the right ?!]

**Click** the **green triangle** (my first image) to start debugging (or press <kbd>F5</kbd>) and pay attention to the terminal output (in VS code).

NOTE: 
If you attach break points, by clicking on the line numbers, indicated with red dots, you can use the `Debug Console` (left of `Terminal` tab)as a namespace environment to check variables etc (much like Quokka), during control flow evaluation.

I took this snippet from the [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging). It's a solid read.

Comment: Thanks @Tobiah. Incidentally, if launch.json doesn't exist this needs to be inside a .vscode directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to this.
I had this working as accepted answer with the "Chrome debugger" plugin, which is now deprecated and the built-in js-debug is referenced as the replacement. I spent a good 2 hours for this to work with Angular yesterday. I tried both using the node configuration and also the chrome and edge type like the documentation says should work. Didn't get it to work.

What actually solved it for me was:

- `ng serve` in the terminal to bring up the angular dev server on https://localhost:4200 (I have added a localhost certificate to use SSL/TLS, out of the box, dev server runs on http)
- open chrome and go to https://localhost:4200
- using `ctrl+shift+P` `>Debug: Open Link` and then typing the url https://localhost:4200 to my dev chrome instance

It is now attached properly and the debug console is reflecting that it is actually attached. I can set break points and debug the code.

I should add that I am running WSL and using vs code remote to point to my WSL instance, where my code also resides, within the wsl filesystem.

[Typescript debugging documentation, Angular](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

## React Debugging

There is an awesome section in the official VS Code docs that explains how to debug React apps:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_debugging-react

In short, you need to ...

1. Run your app using `npm start`
2. Create a `launch.json` file with the following contents

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
          }
    ]
}
```

3. After your app is running, launch the new run configuration using the green arrow in VS Code