# Visual Studio Code - Javascript Errors Do Not Show File and Line

Tags: visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

I am new to Visual Studio Code.

An error occurred in my javascript. In the console it said:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

But had underneath:

```
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

I have Chrome Debugger installed in Visual Studio Code.

However, when I go the the Chrome Browser, when the program is running, and I look at the Console in the Developer Tools, it tells me the File and line number where the nefarious error occurred.

**Why is it not showing this in Visual Studio Code?**

**How can I get it to show it in Visual Studio Code?**

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003292/debugging-javascript-in-vs-code-console

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly no. That guy did not know how to start debugging. I am debugging with the Chrome Debugging Installed in Visual Studio Code. Its telling me there is an error in the console, but not telling me what line and what file where the error occurred. As many people know who have use the inbuilt Developer Tools in the Chrome browser, you get told the offending line and file. Visual Studio Code seems a big step forward in the IDE department, but a huge leap backwards in the Debugging department when compared to Chrome Browser Developer Tools.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? A similar thing is happening to me - for me its with the Firefox Debugging Tools for VS Code, and I do not have the "no debugger available" message but I do have the original error showing without a file nor a line number. I could've swore that a couple days ago, it *did* show the line and file for errors output in the Debug Console, but not today apparently... Not sure if this is an intermittent issue or what...

Comment: @dwillis - I am the OP - I did not do anything, but recently, possibly after an auto-update in Jan 2022, I have started to notice errors are often being tagged with the file and line number. Sometimes, still some errors do not catch in the VSC, so I start Chrome Debugger and the error is reported there. Its possibly getting better for me, but not quite perfect yet.